# C++ having problems with PThreads, not compiling

Tags: c++, pthreads

The following function seems to be the cause of the problem"

```
template <class Type>
void * server_work(void * arg)
{
    int ii;
    int cno;
    Server<Type> * server = (Server<Type> *) arg;
    Customer<Type> newcust;

    for(ii=0; ii<QUEUE_LENGTH; ii++)
    {
        size_t length = rand()%(MAX_RANGE-MIN_RANGE)+MIN_RANGE ; // Generate the number, assign to variable.
        pthread_mutex_lock(&MUTEX);
        cno=CUSTOMER_COUNT;
        CUSTOMER_COUNT++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&MUTEX);

        newcust=Customer<Type>(cno, cno,cno,length);

        if(CUSTOMER_COUNT<=QUEUE_LENGTH)
        {
            server->IncreaseNumOfCustomers();

            for(size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
            {
                newcust.getLinkedList().insertFirst(1000);
            }
            server->getCustomers()[ii]=newcust;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

The problem occurs when the compiler reads the following bit of code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{


    pthread_t threads[NUMBER_OF_SERVERS];
    int i,j;


    if(pthread_mutex_init(&MUTEX, NULL))
    {
        cout<<"Unable to initialize a MUTEX"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Server<int> servs[NUMBER_OF_SERVERS];

    for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SERVERS; i++)
    {
        servs[i].setServerNum(i);
        pthread_create(threads+i, NULL, server_work, (void *)&servs[i]);//<<--compiler flags here
    }

    // Synchronization point
    for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SERVERS; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(*(threads+i), NULL);
    }

    cout<<"SERVER-NO\tCUSTOMER-NO\tARRIVAL-TIME\tWAITING-TIME\tTRANSACTION-TIME"<<endl;
    for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SERVERS; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<servs[i].getCustomersServed(); j++)
        {
            cout<<i<<"\t\t"<<servs[i].getCustomers()[j].getCustomerNumber()<<"\t\t"<<servs[i].getCustomers()[j].getArrivalTime()<<"\t\t"<<servs[i].getCustomers()[j].getWaitingTime()<<"\t\t"<<servs[i].getCustomers()[j].getTransactionTime()<<endl;

        }

    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
```

I get the following error from the compiler:

> main.cpp:84:71: error: no matches converting function ‘server_work’ to type ‘void* (*)(void*)’
>       main.cpp:26:8: error: candidate is: template void* server_work(void*)

Comment: The error messages seem clear enough. BTW, did you consider using C++11 and its `std::thread` ?

Comment: Why on Earth are you using a template?

Comment: LoL, its a project..Our lecturer likes torturing us. I tried changing the function implementation but get the same Error, i will look up on std:: threads now!

Comment: probably `server_work` should be static as pthread_create doesn't know which instance you want, and being a Class the argument `void *arg` become `this` that's why the compiler look for `()(void)` (but maybe I'm still sleeping and that's a nightmare)

Comment: Sorry your lecturer is not *torturing* but trying to *teach* you things and make you *learn*

Comment: I don't think `static` is the right thing (unless it's a member function of a class - but it doesn't look like it is) - something like `serverwork<T>`, where `T` is the type you want the server to "work on". I'm not entirely sure exactly how you'd write it, and I've got something else to do right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong prototype:

```
template <class Type>
void * server_work(void * arg)
```

While pthread is expecting something like this

```
void * server_work(void * arg)
```

---

However it's not so hard to workaround this, for instance:

```
void* CoolWrapper(void* arg)
{
     return server_work<desired_type>(arg);
}
```